Is a Cleric multiclass the only way to gain Heavy Armor proficiency with a 1 level dip?
I have a character whose 1st level was in Sorcerer. For thematic reasons, he has a very bad dexterity score which I anticipate will catch up with him. Therefore, at some point down the line, I will want him to start wearing heavy armor and I don't want to spend feats to do it.
I believe in the 2014 rules, the only way to gain heavy armor proficiency with a 1 level dip was multiclassing into Cleric and picking an appropriate domain that gave you the proficiency. Is it correct that this is the still the case in the 2024 rules, but instead of picking an appropriate domain you have to pick the Protector Divine Order?

Pretty much yes
5e 2024 has not added any other options to gain Heavy Armor proficiency with a level 1 dip than the one you describe (Cleric, pick Protector divine order). 1
While the Fighter and Paladin get Heavy armor proficiency at first character level, if you multiclass into them, you only get Light and Medium armor and Shields profiency.
One way to get it with a one-level "dip" would be to use one of those classes as a starting level, but obviously that is not an option for you any more (and would cost you other things you get starting as Sorcerer, like the Sorcerer's saves and proficiencies).

1 There is a lot of 2014 legacy content out there that has not been superceded, so it might be that there is some obscure 2014 option I am missing for this, but if there was none, none has been added. According to the conversion guidelines of WotC, the Nature and Tempest domains for clerics can still be used from the 2014 edition, and provide proficiency with Heavy Armor at first level, but based on statements by Jeremy Crawford, and the way the subclasses are written in 2024, you would get those only at third level now.

I don't believe you can get Nature or Tempest domains at 1st level in the 2024 rules. IIRC all subclasses are gained at 3rd level, even legacy ones.

@RyanC.Thompson I wondered about that, too, and could find no guidance about this, concluding that if they say you can use the old classes, then likely as is. But I easily might have missed this if it is somewhere other than the linked page from my answer or the PHB.. I asked a question on it now. If you have a source for it, would be great to answer there with citation, and I’ll take it out here.

The relevant question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/213752/28580
