When playing a legacy subclass from 2014, at what level do you gain your subclass features?
In D&D 5e, all character classes now gain their subclass at 3rd level. For example, clerics now select their domain at 3rd level.
The official statement for changes under the 2024 rules for the 2024 PHB says:

Using This Book with Older Books
When you play D&D with the 2024 Player’s Handbook, it replaces all rules, classes, subclasses, spells, feats, equipment, species, and backgrounds in the 2014 version of the book. There are a few exceptions; the following options don’t appear in the 2024 book and are still usable from 2014

This is followed by a list of still available subclasses that includes the three dropped cleric domains (Knowledge, Nature, Tempest) all of which were gained at first level, and the four missing schools of magic for wizards (necromancy, transmutation, conjuration, enchantment), all of which were gained at 2nd level.
It however does not say anything about moving the subclass features to third level.
The same question applies to legacy subclasses from Xanathar's and Tasha's and other books like warlock, wizard or cleric subclasses that were not included in the new PHB
How does it work until new 2024 versions of these subclasses get published? Do you play them as written, gaining these features at their legacy level, or do you have to move the subclass features that are gained earlier to third level?

I read your link on the other question yesterday and had exactly this thought! They didn't do a very good job of explaining it at all.

At level 3
Regarding subclasses, every class in the 2024 PHB has the following sentence at level 3:

[...] A subclass is a specialization that grants you features at
certain [class] levels. For the rest of your career, you gain each of
your subclass's features that are of your [class] level or lower.

With the 2024 PHB rules, all legacy subclasses must follow this same rule. This means that everything you would have gained from the subclass before level 3 is now obtained at level 3.
This is also supported by several interviews with Jeremy Crawford, Lead Designer of Dungeons & Dragons 5th Edition, before the release of the new 2024 PHB. Here is a transcription of one of them (*). Emphasis mine:

[...] an important nuance about using the 2024 PHB is that it replaces
game options that appear in it and in the 2014 PHB. What that means is
if there's an option, a subclass, a feat or something else that's in
2014 but not in 2024 you can still use the 2014 version, so a great
example: The Necromancer subclass does not appear in the Wizard class
in the 2024 PHB that means the 2024 wizard can use the 2014
Necromancer [...]
[...] the 2024 replaces material that is replicated from 2014 but if
the thing that was in 2014 does not appear in 2024 you can still use
the 2014 versions of the Necromancer, the Tempest Domain [...] similar
principle with any subclasses or other options in books like XGtE or
TCoE. If the option in that other book is not replaced by something in
the 2024 PHB you can use it, so here's a great example: the Psi
Warrior appears in the 2024 PHB meaning that Psi Warrior now replaces
the Psi Warrior that was in TCoE but the Forge Domain, to get to your
question, that appears in XGtE does not appear in the 2024 PHB meaning
you can use it and we have designed the subclass rules so that they
tell you essentially how an older subclass works because what the
Cleric subclass feature tells you is that when you get your subclass
you get every feature from the subclass that is of your level and
lower and we worded it that way knowing that you might be picking a
subclass for the cleric that used to have first level features or
second level features, so it's essentially if you're making a 2024
cleric and you pick your subclass you get every feature up to that
level in that subclass. So basically the 2024 players handbook covers
you. It tells you just get it all at once. You catch up when you get
the subclass at third level [...]
[...] the class basically gives you your guidance [...] the rules text
tells you now how to get the features from your subclass [...]

(*) New D&D 2024 Player's Handbook: Jeremy Crawford Explains Backwards Compatibility
Other interviews on how backwards compatibility works

Dungeons & Dragons: How Backwards Compatibility Works in 2024 Player’s Handbook
Jeremy Crawford Explains D&D Player's Handbook 2024's Biggest Changes


Thank you. Jeremies answer is a super convoluted way of saying that you have to wait until 3rd level to get all the features from legacy subclasses, and of course is not published rules text anywhere, just something he stated in an interview, but at least it is a clear indication of designer intent.

@NobodytheHobgoblin It's a pleasure! I'd like to add more references—I'll do that throughout the day.

I agree with the answer in terms of the level, but I don't read that first quote in the same way. It is explaining what happens after level 3, and doesn't say anything about before level 3. It is there to replace the words 'subclass feature' in the class tables I think.

@SeriousBri I've added a couple of interviews. For example, in the newly linked video, JC says again that the wording for the rule I quoted in my answer has that intent (see https://youtu.be/1-4mPDrylfo?t=214)

@NobodytheHobgoblin I think the clearer way Jeremy could have put it is that the gaining of a subclass is a cleric (class) feature, which, by 2024 rules, now happens at level 3. If that subclass is legacy, we have this clarification that yes, you then also acquire legacy L1 and L2 subclass content at that time.

@nitsua60 Agreed, it would have been a clearer way to state it. The way it is now is incredibly indirect and in-explicit in the both rules and change announcement page. They wouldn't need to explain this in interviews all the time if it was clear from the way the rules are written.
